# run "sudo R CMD javareconf" get "Cannot find any Java interpreter"

Tags: java, r, ubuntu

I tried to install a plugin for eclipse,but get an error,after some googling,got a suggestion to run
:sudo R CMD javareconf,but got this error:

```
*** Cannot find any Java interpreter
*** Please make sure 'java' is on your PATH or set JAVA_HOME correspondingly
```

By the way,my $JAVA_HOME points to a oracle-jdk-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, your root user doesn't have a JAVA_HOME set. Do you absolutely need to `sudo` it?

If you do, you could use a small bash script to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME="<path to jdk>"
R CMD javareconf
```

Save the file and give it a name like `myinstall` or something like that, perform a `chmod +x myinstall` and `sudo ./myinstall`

**EDIT**

@Mat pointed out a good point. I changed my approach. Thanks!